# Why does my function return [AsyncFunction: repo]?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, axios, github-api

I'm trying to use the async/await functionality to build a node JS script. I currently have a file called `repo.js` as a helper file to get data from Github's API and return it to a variable for me to access elsewhere in different JS files of my node application, `repo.js` is as such:

```js
const axios = require('axios')

const repo = async () => {
  const data = await axios.get('https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/releases', {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'token MYTOKEN'
    }
  })
  return data
}

exports.repo = repo
```

And then in my `main.js` file I'm trying to do...

```js
const repo = require('./src/utils/repo')

program
  .option('-d, --debug', 'output extra debugging')
  .option('-s, --small', 'small pizza size')
  .option('-p, --pizza-type <type>', 'flavour of pizza')

const repoData = repo.repo
console.log(repoData)
```

Unfortunately, this just returns `[AsyncFunction: repo]` to the console which isn't the intended behaviour. Why can't I access the contents here?

**UPDATE**

Based on some responses I've been given, I'm aware of the fact I need my code inside of a async function or to use `.then()`. The issue is, I don't want to put all of my application's code inside of a `.then()` just to rely on one thing from an API.

Example:

```js
var version = ''
repo.getRepoDetails().then((res) => {
  version = res.data[0].body.tag_name
})
```

Now I have access to `version` everywhere.

Comment: You are logging the function itself, you are not executing it: `const repoData = repo.repo()`

Comment: The title and the question here appear to be totally unrelated.

Comment: @Reyno Sweet, the issue though is when I run my script, the console log outputs `Promise { <pending> }` which isn't the data from the Github API. Because the data is still pending, how can I get this to wait and then output to console?

Comment: @RyanHolton You need to put your code inside an [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and use [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) to get the data. Or use the [then](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) notation from a promise

Comment: @RyanHolton if you're using NodeJS you could upgrade to version [14.3 >](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v14.3.0/) with the flag `--experimental-top-level-await`. This will remove your need for async / await or then.

Answer (score 0):

Every async/await function is a promise, meaning that you need to wait for it to finish in order to read it's result.

```
repo.repo().then(res => console.log(res))
```

If you application is a simple nodejs script(or single file) then you can wrap your code inside an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) like this:

```
const repo = require('./src/utils/repo')

(async () => {
  program
    .option('-d, --debug', 'output extra debugging')
    .option('-s, --small', 'small pizza size')
    .option('-p, --pizza-type <type>', 'flavour of pizza')

  const repoData = await repo.repo() <--- You can use await now instead of then()
  console.log(repoData)
})()
```

Comment: Great, but then this means I've got to put all of my application's code inside the `.then()` because I only need to get one item from the API and store it in a variable for me to use elsewhere

Comment: Check my updated description. If I'm only getting one thing from the API, surely I don't have to nest all of my functions inside one another just to get one thing?

Comment: Unfortunately if you want to use the response of a promise, you need to handle it as a promise in every level upwards that you want to use it

Answer (score -1):

Async function always return promise object so you can access the result using promise.then() like

```
repo.repo().then(result => result)
```

Comment: Imagine I needed to get the version from Github's API from a repo to use in my JS, does this mean I need all of my application's code inside of the `.then()` just to rely on that one thing? Surely that's the idea of something like: `const version = await myFunc()` for instance.